# How to make file upload field mandatory

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Hello can anyone plz fix this problem.

my input field is below code and I am doing validation on form submit i.eis:

```
<input name="file[]" type="file" multiple="multiple">

<form name="bdmrequest" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" onsubmit="return(validate());">
```

i have included validate.js in header and i am able to do validation of other fields except file upload. 
validation code i am using:

```
if(document.bdmrequest.file.value== "")
  {
   alert("Attachment Required");
   document.bdmrequest.file.focus();
    return false;
  }
```

js doesn't support me to use  (document.bdmrequest.file[].value== "")
please suggest me the alternatives. the name of my input type has to be file[] only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you need pure Javascript: **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Uta/)**

```
function validate(){
    var inp = document.getElementById('upload');
    if(inp.files.length === 0){
        alert("Attachment Required");
        inp.focus();

        return false;
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
function validate(){

    if($('#upload')[0].files.length === 0){
        alert("Attachment Required");
        $('#upload').focus();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this javascript works only when validate function is written in same page as that of form page. but i have created validate.js in separate file and i am giving link to it in form page head tag. This doesn't recognize document.getElementById('upload');

Answer (score 8):

No need of JavaScript validation 
you can use "required" attribute in input type....

```
 <input type="file" required="required">
```

Comment: The HTML5 required attribute marks any input/textarea as being required to have a value before the form can be submitted.

Answer (score 5):

You can check if the value is empty.

```
<input name="file[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" id="uploadField">
```

And then in js:

```
if($("#uploadField").val() != ""){
      //your success code here
}
```